# Is this correct behaviour for a Ruby hash with a default value?

Tags: ruby

```
hash = Hash.new(Hash.new([]))
hash[1][2] << 3

hash[1][2] # => [3]
hash # => {}
hash.keys # => []
hash.values # => []
```

What's going on? Ruby's hiding data (1.9.3p125)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What's going on? Ruby's hiding data (1.9.3p125)

Ruby hides neither data nor its [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-c-new).

Default value you pass into the `Hash` constructor is returned whenever the key is not found in the hash. But this default value is never actually stored into the hash on its own.

To get what you want you should use `Hash` constructor with block and store default value into the hash yourself (on both levels of your nested hash):

```
hash = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] } } 

hash[1][2] << 3

p hash[1][2]  #=> [3]
p hash        #=> {1=>{2=>[3]}}
p hash.keys   #=> [1]
p hash.values #=> [{2=>[3]}]
```

Comment: Accepting this answer for providing the correct form of what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple. If you pass an object to a Hash constructor, it'll become a default value for all missing keys in that hash. What's interesting is that this value is mutable. Observe:

```
hash = Hash.new(Hash.new([]))
# mutate default value for nested hash
hash[1][2] << 3

# default value in action
hash[1][2] # => [3]
# and again
hash[1][3] # => [3]
# and again
hash[1][4] # => [3]

# set a plain hash (without default value)
hash[1] = {}

# what? Where did my [3] go?
hash[1][2] # => nil

# ah, here it is!
hash[2][3] # => [3]
```

Comment: I don't think that's what OP is actually asking about, but it's definitely the next pitfall in using default values with Ruby hashes. Nice explanation.

Comment: Good work on your part too. +1'd :)

Answer (score 0):

I get a try with this in irb.
Seams Ruby does not tag element as "visible" except affecting value over default explicitly via = for instance.

```
hash = Hash.new(Hash.new([]))
hash[1] = Hash.new([])
hash[1][2] = [3]
hash
#=> {1=>{2=>[3]}}
```

May be some setters are missing this "undefaulting" behavior ...